# I want to create multiple enemies but keep getting same error code

Tags: pygame, pycharm

Blockquote I just started coding in this coronatime and I am running into a problem. 
The error code is 
 enemy_icon = [i] 
 NameError: name 'i' is not defined

And i'm not sure why. I having been looking online but couldn't find any answers.
 Hopefully this has given enough resources to be a good enough question.

```
   import pygame
   import random
   import math

   pygame.init()

   # game over logo
   game_over = pygame.image.load("game-over.png")

   # create screen
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
   background = pygame.image.load("8717.jpg")

   # Title + Logo
   pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
   icon = pygame.image.load("chicken.png")
   pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

   # Player icon
   player_icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
   playerX = 400
   playerY = 500

   player_changeX = 0
   player_changeY = 0

   # multiple enemy players
   enemy_icon = [i]
   enemyX = [i]
   enemyY = [i]
   enemy_changeX = [i]
   enemy_changeY = [i]
   num_of_enemies = 2

   for i in range(num_of_enemies):
       enemy_icon.append(pygame.image.load("space-invaders.png"))
       enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 936))
       enemyY.append(random.randint(-100, -50))
       enemy_changeX.append(random.randint(-2, 2))
       enemy_changeY.append(random.randint(1, 2))

   # bullet #ready you can't see bullet. fire you can
   bullet = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
   bulletX = 0
   bulletY = 0
   bulletY_change = 2
   bulletX_change = 0
   bullet_state = "ready"

   # score
   score = 0


   def player(x, y):
       screen.blit(player_icon, (x, y))


   def enemy(x, y, i):
       screen.blit(enemy_icon[i], (x, y))

   def fire_bullet(x, y):
       global bullet_state
       bullet_state = "fire"
       screen.blit(bullet, (x + 16, y + 10))


   def has_collided(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
       distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
       if distance < 27:
           return True
       else:
           return False

   def collided(enemyX, enemyY, playerX, playerY):
       distance2 = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - playerX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - playerY, 2)))
       if distance2 < 27:
           return True
       else:
           return False


   # game loop
   running = True
   while running:

       # background round colour RGB
       screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
       # background image
       screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               running = False
       # If key pressed check whether its right or left
           if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   player_changeX = -5
               if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   player_changeX = 5
               if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                   player_changeY = -5
               if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                   player_changeY = 5
               # bullet shot
               if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   if bullet_state == "ready":
                       bulletX = playerX
                       bulletY = playerY
                       fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
           if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
               if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   player_changeX = 0
               if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                   player_changeY = 0

       # If player reaches boarder
       if playerX >= 936:
       playerX = 20
       if playerX <= 0:
           playerX = 936
       if playerY <= 0:
           playerY = 0
       if playerY >= 550:
           playerY = 550
       # enemy control
       for i in range(num_of_enemies):
           if enemyX[i] >= 936:
               enemyX[i] = 20
           if enemyX[i] <= 0:
               enemyX[i] = 936
           if enemyY[i] <= 0:
               enemyY[i] = 0
           if enemyY[i] >= 550:
               enemyY[i] = random.randint(-100, -50)
           # collision bullet and enemy
           collision = has_collided(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
           if collision:
               bulletY = playerY
               bulletX = playerX
               bullet_state = "ready"
               score += 1
               print(score)
               enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 936)
               enemyY[i] = random.randint(-100, -50)
               enemy_changeX[i] = random.randint(-2, 2)
               enemy_changeY[i] = random.randint(1, 2)
           collision2 = collided(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], playerX, playerY)
           if collision2:
               screen.blit(game_over, (400, 100))
               score = 0
               playerY = 400
               playerX = 500
           enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

       # bullet movement
       if bullet_state == "fire":
           fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
           bulletY -= bulletY_change

       if bulletY <= 0:
           bullet_state = "ready"

       # collision enemy and player


       # Player coordinates
       playerX += player_changeX
       playerY += player_changeY

       # enemy change in coordinates
       enemyX += enemy_changeX
       enemyY += enemy_changeY

       # bullet change in y
       bulletY -= bulletY_change

       # Results
       player(playerX, playerY)

       pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Because you're using the variable `i` before you define it in the `for` loop below. I think you don't understand array definition syntax. What is `enemy_icon` and all those other variables supposed to be? If you do `i = 20` and then `enemy_icon = [i]` then `enemy_icon` with be a list with one element: the number 20 `enemy_icon` will be `[20]`. Python lists can grow to be as big as you want, you don't declare their size like you do in Java. If you want to initialize all those variable to be empty lists, then change your code to `enemy_icon = []` and `enemyX = []` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear. You have this line in you code:

```
   # multiple enemy players
   enemy_icon = [i]
```

This line says that you are trying to create a variable **enemy_icon** and initialize it to a list with one element in it. That element is the variable **i** which has not been previously defined. I suspect that the i is a typo and that you are really trying to initialize with an empty list, in which case just remove the **i** like this:

```
   # multiple enemy players
   enemy_icon = []
```

The same is true for the 4 variables right after that.

Comment: i tried it the error went away but now I have no enemy icons. Could you help me with that? Before a person said i should make i global would that help. If yes how would I make i global. I could do it the long way by making new images but is there a shorter way.

Comment: A quick look at the code looks like you should be creating 2 enemies inside that for loop. You are creating them off the top of the screen though `enemyY.append(random.randint(-100, -50))`. For debugging purposes you might try changing the initial y values so that they start on the screen instead. Also you should really create a class for the player, enemy and bullet to keep all of the related information together instead of instead of in separate combined lists like enemyX and enemyY. As a last comment the best and simplest approach would be for you to investigate and use the sprites module.

Comment: Just wanted to get your attention back :). As i asked a new question. I gave it back to you.